# Windows: start a new process hidden (no window)

Tags: java, windows, exec, hide, vlc

I want to execute a 3rd party program (VLC in my case) without any window popping up in Windows. I am running my java program as a Windows service which works fine, but when I start VLC using `Runtime.exec()` then a window pops up, no matter what I do. There's command line arguments to VLC that prevent the GUI but then a black console pops up - not much better.

So: Any idea how to start an external program from Java so that no visible window shows up? (It works just fine in Mac OS X and I assume Linux will be the same)

I know there is a way to directly integrate `libVLC` into your Java program but that option does not work for me.

Comment: *"..directly integrate `libVLC` into your Java program but that option does not work for me"*  It seems you are better off fixing that.

Comment: that's a license issue. Would be forced to publish all my code in GPL and that's unfortunately not an option :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better solution than this, but this *should* work.

If you have Windows Scripting installed (standard on Win98 and newer) save the following line as a `.vbs` file (`invisible.vbs`, for example).

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

This script allows you to run any `.bat` file invisibly with the following command:

```
wscript.exe "C:\Path\To\File\invisible.vbs" "C:\Path\To\Another\File\BatFile.bat"
```

This builds on [cheeken's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936486/758280) answer because it will allow you to hide the cmd console. All you have to do is create a `.bat` file with `start vlc` in it.

Note: If you execute a `.bat` file with this script, it has to close itself and it cannot throw an error which causes it to hang. If it does it will stick around until shutdown or until you close it through the task manager.

Comment: That's a pretty nasty workaround, but it works! (I did not get the `.bat` version to work, but instead ran the `vlc.exe` directly from the vbs script with `--intf=rc` parameter). Thanks a lot!!

Comment: some more details how I got it to work: a vbs file with this as content: `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"" --intf=rc " & WScript.Arguments(0) & """, 0, False` and then simply execute it via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript.exe \"C:\\test.vbs\" \"--rc-host=127.0.0.1:34123\"");` . Works exactly as expected (in this case opening the vlc telnet remote control interface). Thanks again!

Comment: one more question: do you know how to grab standard out from the started program? seems like that gets lost on the way...

Comment: @Daniel I have no idea. I used this work around to do some file associations behind the scenes, I never needed the stdout. I'd be interested to know how you figure it out though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the VLC binary directly in your console command, try calling [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) against that command (i.e., `start c:\vlc.exe`).

Note that this call will return more or less immediately (so if your application is depending upon the call returning in order to determine when VLC has been terminated, it will have to yield some other way).

Comment: If the you need the `start` call to return when VLC terminates, use the `/WAIT` option.

Comment: I tried that, does not work. `start` is a feature of the cmd console and not a file you can execute. I also tried `cmd /c start vlc`. Works, but then I see the cmd console instead of the vlc console. not a solution either :(