# Sending a process to background in vbs

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I am using a code like,

```
Dim sh
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.run "cmd /K a.exe & exit",0,false
Set sh = Nothing
```

It works fine to start a background process. But when, i call a.bat file contained,

```
start b.bat
```

then b.bat is not hiding. which way is batter to hide b.bat also? can i take this b.bat from foreground to background?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936451/windows-start-a-new-process-hidden-no-window

Comment: this answer is not useful to me. i want to send a visible opened window to background.`sh.run "vlc.exe",0,false` this will open vlc in background.

Comment: What do you mean by "send to the background"? Do you mean "minimise"?

Comment: not minimize. say about vlc.exe, when it will play a song, how can i make it hidden, after start playing?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `0` (hidden) as the 2nd param to `Run()` *does* hide the batch file. But it doesn't hide the windows of any programs launched *by* the batch file.

So... is your `BAT` file trying to launch a program? If so, can it be launched by VBScript instead so that it may be hidden?

On a side note, you know you can use `CMD /C` in lieu of `CMD /K "... & Exit"`, right?

Comment: `But it doesn't hide the windows of any programs launched by the batch file.` yes but how can i take that program (opened by hidden batch file) from foreground to background?

Comment: You can't. That's why I was suggesting that you open them via VBScript instead of your batch file, where you _can_ specify them as hidden.